# what will be the value of 'this'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know this because i have to change cell style during editing from menu button like spreadsheet.below code is not working properly.

```
$("#tab1 tr td:not(:first-child)").on("click", function (e) {          
    console.log(e);
    if(e.currentTarget.contentEditable != null){
         $(e.currentTarget).attr("contentEditable",true);
     }
     else{
         $(e.currentTarget).append("<input type='text'>");
     }
});
//Add bold text
$("#tab1 tr td:not(:first-child)").on("click", function () { 
   var mytd=this;
   $("#btn4 li a:eq(0)").on("click",function() {
     $(mytd).toggleClass("bold");
     $(this).toggleClass("bg");
   });
});
```

Comment: $(this) points to `$("#tab1 tr td:not(:first-child)")` , that all other `td` than the first one

Comment: it will point to <td> tag

Answer (score 1):

it will be `td`. do a `console.log($(this).html())` to find out.

Answer (score 1):

try to do following

`console.log(e.target);`

**Note** that you have to pass e as argument in the function parameter

Comment: What does `e.target` have to do with the value of `this`? There's no guarantee that they'll be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try also as per @Jitesh Tukadiya said,
console.log(e.target);

you can also use debug your self, to display alert(); with different arguments and analyze what it gives .

Use debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in an event handler is usually equal to [`event.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/), unless you have explicitly manipulated the scope using [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), [`Object.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or similar techniques.

I usually use `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` in event handlers because it is more explicit and allows the function to have an easily rebindable scope var. (E.g., you can use an event handler which is a property of another object and bind it to that instance.)